# Different element have the same attributes not displaying the same results

Tags: html, css

**Am sorry if there's another question like this out there, I just don't know how to put the question and I've searched for others that looks like mine but can't find any with the same problem as mine.**

I am designing a **Responsive Web Design** site which works fine to my taste on Mozilla Firefox because I design with it but I tried opening the site on Google Chrome and Opera, the navigation leaves a space which can be filled with either adding padding or height and by doing that it'll affect the page on Mozilla.

Website: http://hwebtest.orgfree.com
[image]

*The website is located on a free hosting server because it's on development.*

Thanks for taking time to read my post. All reviews are appreciated.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a [**link to an example or site**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: To me they look absolutely identical on both Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: You should wrap navigation & searchPanel in a div or what-ever-ement with black background or as you said, set explicit height to both. If you wanna have equal height on both elements you also can set what-ever-parent-element to display:flex

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply... I'll be trying your suggestion (mumomono)